# Creating a simple redirect userscript

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey, userscripts

I am trying to make a simple redirect userscript for `cbc.ca`.

They have a "lite" version located at `https://www.cbc.ca/lite/news`.

And when you go to a news article the url is `https://www.cbc.ca/lite/news/1.1111111`, for example, where the numbers at the end reference the article. The same article on the full website would be located at, for example, `https://www.cbc.ca/news/canada/something/a-very-long-descriptive-title-1.1111111`

So far I have this:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name Redirect to CBC Lite
// @include *.cbc.ca/news/*
// @run-at document-start
// @grant none
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    // create a new MutationObserver
    var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
        location.href = location.href.replace(/news\/[\D]*/, 'lite/story/');
    });

    observer.observe(document, {
        childList: true,
        subtree: true
    });
})();
```

Which works, but I am required to refresh the page to make it do so. What do I need to add to make it work directly?

**Small Update:**

Now looks like this, still requires refresh to load:

```
const url = new URL(window.location.href);
const story_id = location.pathname.split('-').pop();
const lite_host = "https://www.cbc.ca/lite/story/";
const new_url = lite_host + story_id;

location.href = new_url;
```

Comment: Why do you need the `MutationObserver`? Shouldn't a simple `location.href = \`https://www.cbc.ca/lite/story/${location.pathname.split('-').pop()}\`` suffice?

Comment: I've made a change based on what you suggest @double-beep

It still works, but I still need to refresh the page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the page doesn't reload each time you click a new article, hence the reason your script didn't work. You need to watch for URL changes. One way to do this is by using [the `urlchange` event](https://www.tampermonkey.net/documentation.php#_grant) (only available to Tampermonkey)

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Redirect to CBC Lite
// @author       bbbhltz
// @description  Prefer the lite CBC version
// @version      0.0.1
// @match        *.cbc.ca/*
// @run-at       document-start
// @grant        window.onurlchange
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    function redirect() {
        const pathname = location.pathname;
        if (!pathname.startsWith('/news')) return;

        const storyId = pathname.split('-').pop();

        location.href = `https://www.cbc.ca/lite/story/${storyId}`;
    }

    window.addEventListener('urlchange', ({ url }) => {
        if (!url.startsWith('https://www.cbc.ca/news/')) return;

        redirect();
    });

    redirect();
})();
```